# mysql query result. converting three columns value to one row in result and ordering it by first column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

values in the table
Source table:

```
column1 column2 column3
1         6      2
1         6      4
1         6      3
1         7      2
1         7      3
1         7      4
2         8      5
2         8      1
```

Expected result:

```
1 6 7 2 3 4
2 8 1 5
```

For all column1 value:"1" I need the second column value first and 3rd column value to continue in a single row as mentioned in Expected result. 
same case for column2 value: "2" i need all the values in single row.

Please suggest possible solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be close enough:

```
SELECT col1
     , CONCAT_WS(
       ' ',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col2 SEPARATOR ' '),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col3 SEPARATOR ' ')
     ) as cnct
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col1
```

[See live example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05dda/1)

EDIT: [even better](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05dda/3):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(
       ' ',
       col1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col2 ORDER BY col2 SEPARATOR ' '),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col3 ORDER BY col3 SEPARATOR ' ')
     ) as cnct
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
SELECT Concat(column1, ' ', Group_concat(DISTINCT column2 SEPARATOR ' '), ' ', 
              Group_concat(DISTINCT column3 SEPARATOR ' ')) 
FROM   tsts 
GROUP  BY column1
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab44d/5)